# Return data async inside emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a background process written in node.js that is using the EventEmitter like this:

```
var event = { returnValue: undefined };
eventEmitter.emit('name', event, argument);
return event.returnValue; // Example of doing things with event.returnValue.
```

Other end of the event:

```
eventEmitter.on('name', (event, argument) => {
    var returnValue = await asyncMethod(); // <- This method returns a Promise, so I could use await if possible or some other solution.
    event.returnValue = returnValue;
});
```

I've tried to find an elegant solution to use asynchronous methods, but since **EventEmitter does not support asynchronous functions** at all, I can't really use await in the function or something similar.
One solution could be to set `returnValue` to a Promise, but that quickly becomes impractical, specially since some of my functions iterate through multiple asynchronous functions.

I need all the code to complete properly before the first block of code continues and tries to use the `event.returnValue`.

Is my only solution to use some third party "synchronize", or hasn't anyone at node.js thought of this problem?

There isn't really any problem for me if the thread is blocked while executing, since this is a background process without any GUI.

Comment: It is not exaclty clear what you mean with `One solution could be to set returnValue to a Promise, but that quickly becomes impractical, specially since some of my functions iterate through multiple asynchronous functions.` and why this is a problem.

Comment: "*One solution could be to set `returnValue` to a Promise*" - yes, that's the way to go. Why do you think it becomes impractical? Can you give an example of that "iteration through multiple asynchronous functions"?

Comment: @Bergi The code quickly becomes cluttered if I have multiple functions returning Promises, or iterating some list or array calling an asynchronous function inside the loop.

Comment: @einord You mean, in the single event callback? Or are you talking about installing multiple event listeners? If the former, you can trivially build a single promise for everything being done with `then` chains, `async`/`await` syntax or `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Bergi please, write an answer showing this if you know an easy way :)

Comment: @einord I just know that promises are the easy way, but I can't give a specific example of multiple functions if I don't know your exact problem

Comment: @Bergi The problem when multiple async functions are called could look liket his: `{ var items = []; item[0] = asyncMethod1();item[1] = asyncMethod2(); event.returnValue = items; /* <- This must be done in sync, since EventEmitter does not seem to support asynchronous code at all */ }`

Comment: @einord `event.returnValue = Promise.all(items)` it is, then.

Comment: @Bergi Nice! That works for arrays. What about more complex objects with more data, where some of it must come from an asynchronous function? Example: `{ var returnItem = { name: 'foo' }; returnItem.moreStuff = asyncMethod1(); event.ReturnValue = returnItem; }`. This would work, but is not practical, since any code trying to use returnItem must know to wait for certain values.

Comment: @einord `Promise.all(['foo', asyncMethod1(), …]).then(([name, moreStuff, …]) => ({name, moreStuff, …}))` (or put the immediately available stuff in the object literal in the `then` handler). You can also use `async`/`await` for sequential stuff.

Comment: @Bergi is `.then(() => {})` not called asynchronously? If so, I still don't get out of the "callback hell", and also have quite messy code.

Comment: @einord Yes, it constructs the object when all individual values are ready. There is no callback hell here, it doesn't nest infinitely - promises do chain.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't really seem to exist any intuitive way to wait for a Promise to resolve synchronously without callbacks, or to use the EventEmitter with async callbacks, **I wrote my own** simple EventEmitter containing an array, and custom `on` and `emit` methods.

It handles asynchronous functions used as parameters properly so I can use it like this:

```
asyncEmitter.on('name', async (event, argument) => {
    event.argument = await asyncMethod(); // Nice and clean code!
});
```

Of course I could develop it further create a `once` function and so on, but for me I really only depend on `on` and `emit`.
I wonder why the node team hasn't solved this yet?